# Stopping a google script on a 0 value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google script that I am working with, which has come together with a lot of help from people.  I would like to stop the script from running if it returns an empty value.  The variable looks at cell 1,3 from a particular spreadsheet.  This is the part of the script in question.

```
var sh7 = sh3.getRange(1,3).getValue(); //Day of the Cycle
if (var sh7 = 0) return;
```

The first line works just fine, but I keep getting a syntax error in the second line.  I am not sure where I am going wrong and I could use some help.

Thank you,

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if (sh7 == 0) {
   return null;
}
```

That should get you a blank return to the cell instead of n/a.

Comment: I gave that a try an I am getting the "Invalid Return" error message when I try to save it.

Comment: So your seeing this error in the spreadsheet cell correct?  And what cell do you want to display this data?  As of right now, the script above is only returning a null value to the script, as far as I can see it's not being written back to the sheet anywhere.

Comment: I am seeing in "Invalid Return" error in the google script.  The cell in the spreadsheet is giving me the #N/A in the cell with the statement that the "Query completed with an empty output.

Comment: It is variable sh7 which would be written into the google doc, but if it comes back with an empty value, I would like the script to stop.

Comment: With out seeing the whole thing, I'm not sure how it's running or when the return is happening.  If that above if statement is firing then that return should stop that function only.

Comment: If it comes back with an empty value and you want it to stop, just replace "return null;" with "break;"?

Answer (score 1):

Use a double-equals:

```
if (sh7 == 0) return;
```

Comment: Okay, I tried that and I get an "Invalid Return" on that line now.  If I look at the spreadsheet that I am pulling it from, I have an #N/A in the cell and it tells me that the "Query completed with an empty output."